# [Ubuntu]Openssh-server doesn’t allow me to login by pubkey

Tags: ssh, operating-system, undefined-behavior, openssh

Recently, I’ve got a trouble on my Ubuntu openssh-server. I’ve done the command on my notebook

```
ssh-copy-id user@IP
```

And I do the things follow on my pc

```
Sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Uncomment the pubkeyauthentication yes
sudo systemctl restart openssh-server
```

Yet it doesn’t work, I still can’t login automatically without password

So I’m confusing and wondering if I could delete or reset some file so that the system can turn back to some default settings?

Thank you guys for helping me. I’m so frustrated on solving this problem…

I’ve copied my pubkey to my pc and assure the authorized keys file has the pubkey I just send

Answer (score 0):

The troubleshooting parts helps me deal with the problem !
Hope that helps !!
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys